# Installing CKEditor with WAMP

Tags: ckeditor, wamp

I'm trying to install CKEditor in WAMP. I downloaded it extracted it in the www folder.

[image]

Here's the HTML code of the *index.php* file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea class="ckeditor" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

I specified the `textarea` class name as **ckeditor** as instructed in the samples but it does not affect the textarea. The CKEditor doesn't appear.

What am I missing here, what should I do to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the JavaScript files of CKEditor, using something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

The `src` depends on where ckeditor.js is localted in relation to your index file.

Also, your textarea needs a name, try adding one like so:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>
```

Comment: I referenced the `ckeditor.js` with the correct path but still no change.

Comment: are there any more files I have to reference?

Comment: Ah, there also needs to be a name on the textarea element, sorry for not catching that!